# Extract data from a dynamic HTML graph using Python

Tags: python, html, python-requests

Trying to extract the most recent financial data from the graphs in the Trading View site, specifically in the Financials section. They provide real time data for earnings and other relevant financial information. I believe they obtain this from an API.

Looking at other questions, this is the code that I have tried, but it gives me an error that I do not understand:

```py
import requests

url = “https://es.tradingview.com/symbols/NASDAQ-ROIV/financials-earnings/“
resp = requests.get(url)
resp = resp.json()
```

Error:
line 5, in  resp = resp.json()

line 975, in json raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the full error traceback. Also if it's HTML why are you using the jsom method? A page can be either HTML or JSON but not both.

Comment: use `resp.content` instead of `resp.json()`

Comment: @Rafaó it gives me the following error: TypeError: 'bytes' object is not callable

Comment: @mousetail added the error! Got the code from another question hoping it would retrieve data in JSON format, much more machine readable